# Add OAuth2 to Existing Django App

Tags: django, oauth, oauth-2.0

I already have a django app running on App Engine, but the current user authentication is provided by Djoser, which uses a simple token authentication.

Now I want to write some new APIs to third party applications to allow them to access user data. So I need to implement the OAuth2.0 authentication.

I found some libraries such as [django-oauth-toolkit](https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit). But the tutorial assumes that you build your app and database from scratch. So I wonder if there's a way to use my current user database to do OAuth2.0 authentication, instead of asking the user to signup again with the same username. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there's no need to start all over again from a new user database. One can continue using whatever authentication methods currently being used to register users. Just write a new app (for the new APIs) and add OAuth2 and run a database migration, which will build several tables needed by OAuth2.

When the OAuth2 authentication process starts, these tables will be filled with grants and access tokens and client application related info.